# Non-existent class error after updating CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter. Now I am upgrading CodeIgniter from 2.2.0 to 3.0.0

I need to use PhpExcel. But it shows an error like:

> Non-existent class: CI_Excel

What can I try next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734173/class-ci-excel-not-found

Comment: it's better to add `require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php";` instead of config. Easy and can widely use/ find example and answers on this manner

Comment: i tried it.but it doesnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'CI\_Excel' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734173/class-ci-excel-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system/ directory is reserved for CI, you're not supposed to modify or put anything in there.

Any custom libraries you use should go into *application/libraries/*.

Answer (score 0):

change the library name As CI_Ex.... and save it on libraries folder